# Ramda, pulling a json index from array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, ramda.js

I have the following array, containing similar JSON objects,

```
[{name: "Abc"}, {name: "Xyz"}, {name: "lmn"}]
```

How can Ramda help me in achieving the following

```
["Abc", "Xyz", "lmn"]
```

Comment: use R.pluck('name', [{name: "Abc"}, {name: "Xyz"}, {name: "lmn"}])

Comment: please add it as an answer, so that i can accept, This works. Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `pluck` function:

```
R.pluck('name', [{name: "Abc"}, {name: "Xyz"}, {name: "lmn"}])
```

Comment: @StepUp: Ramda is a functional programming library; we don't talk about *methods* but about *functions*!  (`R` is not logically an OOP object, but simply a namespace.)

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it using [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Try this:

```js
let array = [{ name: "Abc" }, { name: "Xyz" }, { name: "lmn" }]
let res = array.map((value) => {
  return value.name;
})
console.log(res);
```

Comment: Hi Saurabh, the OP was asking about how Ramda could help, specifically. This solution you suggest doesn't use Ramda at all.

Comment: Sorry, but I still don't see any Ramda in your answer.